# Updating identity column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have connected my asp.net web application to a SQL Server 2012. The problem I am facing is this: I have 5 rows in my table with identity columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Now, the usual thing is when I will delete row no 5 and insert a new row after deletion, the new row should have an id value of 5. But it gets an id value of 6. Similarly, when I delete this row and insert new row, it gets value 7.

So please guide me as to how to get proper id values after deletion.

Comment: The database is behaving properly. Once an identity value is issued, it should never be reused. The value you're getting is indeed proper. You should not depend on identity columns being sequential. If you are, you're using them improperly.

Comment: This is by design. Why are you wanting to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You *are* getting proper values.. however, if you need to reset the count after deletion(bad idea) you need this:

you need `dbcc checkident(tablename,RESEED,5)`

After this statement, the next value inserted will be `6` in the identity column.

REF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Comment: That's not what this question asks at all. You should re-read it.

Comment: @KenWhite I am unable to understand the question beyond "I can't do this, how do I get proper ids after deletion" .. what do you understand from this mate? Please explain..

Comment: KenWhite, if you insert or Delete a row in the data base when the Identity column is set to Auto, then the only way to keep the data from incrementing would be to Reseed the Column.. so inform the rest of us as to why @Aniket answer is incorrect..?

Comment: The problem is that the database is behaving exactly as it should, and the poster needs to understand that; your "fix" isn't one at all. The proper ID after deleting ID 6 and then doing an INSERT is 7, just like if you inserted 6 rows and deleted row 3 the next insert should be 7. (Also note that I didn't downvote as being incorrect; I merely pointed out that the question was based on an erroneous idea that the value was wrong in the first place.)

Comment: the OP demands a fix at the moment. Maybe someday OP may use this later point in time? @KenWhite

Comment: The answer if he wants to keep the inserts in a particular is correct. however the OP needs to understand that what he is seeing is by design if he has the column set for Auto Identity True, however if it isn't then he would have to track his own Id's or create a trigger for example..

Comment: I think the answers the question. The only comment I would make is to read the documentation about `RESEED`, it behaves differently depending on whether rows have been inserted into the table before or not.

Comment: +1 from me I think that totally answers the question

Comment: Changing the identity column manually defeats the purpose of using an identity column in the first place. As I said, I didn't downvote; however, this answer is like someone complaining that their finger hurts when they hit it with a hammer and telling them to take aspirin instead of telling them to stop hitting their finger with the hammer in the first place. An identity should be *unique*, and once it's issued it's been issued, and you shouldn't try to re-use it. If you do, don't bother to use an identity column in the first place.

Comment: Sir, what I wanted to convey is this: after deletion of last row(5th row), the next row that gets added should have the id 5, but it is taking value 6. Also, if 2nd row gets deleted, all the ids of rows below 2nd row should get updated, i.e., row 3rd should become 2nd, 4th should become 3rd, and so on.

Comment: @user2036631 then what you need is a delete trigger. But now I am curious - why do you rely on the autogenerated values?